# Adding HTML tags (e.g. break tag) to embedded Ruby block

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Note: I am a Ruby on Rails newbie so excuse this question if it seems too obvious.  But for the life of me, I can't figure out where to add an HTML break tag  to this Ruby code to make the elements stack on top of each other, not beside each other.

```
<p>
<strong>Genres:</strong>
<%= @book.authors.map {|a| a.name}.join(', ') %>
</p>
```

I have added the break tag after the %> and before it, inside the join method area with the comma, and everywhere else you can imagine and nothing works, it just places the data results beside each other sequentially.  I am sure it's something simply but I can't figure it out.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: You want book authors to appear under a 'Genres' heading?

Comment: Did you try `join('<br/>')`?

Comment: This did not work.  It added the <br> tag as text concatenated with the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical Rails way to do this is with a `for` or `each` loop:

```
<p>
<strong>Authors:</strong>
<% for author in @book.authors %>
<%= author.name %><br/>
<% end %>
</p>
```

The `for` statement could also be `@book.authors.each do |author|`. From an HTML and CSS perspective, I would argue that it is much better to put each author in their own container element such as `<li>`, which can be styled to look the way you want.